# How to Get the current URL of a page which is displayed after accessing a alert box

Tags: java, selenium

Hi What I am currently doing is accessing a webpage "http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/" and then I click on "basic auth"  button and use AutoIT to enter the credentials and click on OK, Now what I am trying to achieve is to get the Current URL of the page that appears soon after I click ok from the alert box.
I am able to enter the details and successfully go to the next page But not able to get the url of that page. I have tried few things but they did not seem to work.
I have used POM and only pasting the code of the test case

```
package scripts;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import pages.BaseAuthLocators;
import sun.rmi.runtime.Log;
import testBase.Base;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;


public class CheckValidBaseAuth extends Base{


    public void Screenshot() throws IOException {
        File src = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        FileUtils.copyFile(src, new File("D:\\workspace\\Dave-Haeffner-s-Practice-Site\\src\\testUtility\\"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".png"));
    }

    @Test
    public void BaseAuthSuccess() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String expectedURL = "http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth";
        String actualURL;

        BaseAuthLocators BaseAuthObj = new BaseAuthLocators(driver);
        String parent=driver.getWindowHandle();
        System.out.println(parent);
        BaseAuthObj.clickBasicAuthLink();
        System.out.println("Clicked Auth Button from webpage");


Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\vishvesh.sawant\\Desktop\\AutoIT Scripts\\HandleAuthenicationWindow.exe");
        //actualURL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        //System.out.println(actualURL);
/*
        try
        {
            Assert.assertEquals(actualURL,expectedURL);
            System.out.println(actualURL);
            Screenshot();
        }
        catch (AssertionError e){
            Log error;
            System.out.println(actualURL);
            Screenshot(); 
        }*/

    }
}
```

**Below is the Error that I am getting:**

```
org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: : 
Build info: version: '3.9.1', revision: '63f7b50', time: '2018-02-07T22:42:22.379Z'
System info: host: 'IN-BOM01-NB04', ip: '10.44.1.158', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_162'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 62.0, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.22.0, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 4136, moz:profile: C:\Users\vishvesh.sawant\Ap..., moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, platformVersion: 10.0, rotatable: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}}
Session ID: a6d6ae04-493e-41ec-a701-ea2cecc4a0a2

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:120)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:160)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:658)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getCurrentUrl(RemoteWebDriver.java:335)
at scripts.CheckValidBaseAuth.BaseAuthSuccess(CheckValidBaseAuth.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:348)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:343)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:305)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:254)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
```

Answer (score 0):

> after clicking the button you could just get it by driver.getCurrentUrl()

Comment: No it does not work and I want the URL after i do the "getRuntime" code.